# Can I have a have a void inside an event handler declaration?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button on my C# Winform, and the following code:

```
button1.Click += button1_Click;
```

and also:

```
private static void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

I am trying to simplify and reduce the amount of code in my application. Is there any way to do this?
Here's what I am trying to achieve:

```
button1.Click +=  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
};
```

This does not work. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an anonymous method:

```
button1.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
   // do something
};
```

But note that you will never be able to unregister this event handler as it is an anonymous method.